# Is there a way to use the current class name in an annotation property (say value) in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

What I want to do is use a general function to define different 'value' properties for one particular/many annotations used in the respective class based on a class-specific unique identifier, of which the most obvious one is the class name.

I'm using NetBeans. I used the Ctrl+Space keyword to check for autocomplete suggestions. There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. What are the possible bottlenecks in doing so?

Some code...

```
@ManagedBean
@CustomScoped(value = uniqueFunction(this.class.name()))
public class DetectionMethodCB extends CommonChildCB<DetectionMethod> implements Serializable {

}
```

Comment: Can you give an example (pseudocode even) of what you're trying to do in code?

Comment: No. Annotation attribute values must be compile-time constants.

Comment: just curious... theoretically why can't it be possible?

Comment: Note that there is no purpose in doing this. The only way you're going to get an instance of the annotation is through the declaring/annotated class. You already have that information.

Comment: That's true. But in my particular case, I'm using JSF Custom Scope which requires controller to have unique scope variable. If I can automate (and not repeat typing a unique name manually) putting the value into the annotation, I can identify the scope (a 'map' which contains properties of the controller bean). Without putting the value parameter, I can't identify the scope to put the controller bean instance into. Maybe it's an annotation configuration problem for JSF... they can auto-identify the scope to instantiate an bean instance and simply require the annotation without value parameter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but it still is a violation of the DRY principle. And you might be able to put an annotation on a class an receive the class of a subclass as a parameter.

Comment: @Jens What is a violation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis repeating the classname of the current class (possibly in multiple places) in a annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible. If you want to specify a class as a value in an annotation you have to use a class literal. So a function is not an option. [From the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.7):

> An element type T is commensurate with an element value V if and only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> [...]
>
> if T is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a class literal
>   (§15.8.2).